# Newbie CSS formatting issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

First question on here. Hope i have posted it correctly.

Following a DOM manipulation YouTube course [here](https://github.com/CodeLab98/DOM-P2-Source-Code/blob/e7c41402bb7165b780205c48a0c1b5e116ef366f/Master%20DOM%20Manipulation%20P2/project-4.js) to make a Javascript stopwatch.

For some reason i can't seem to center my starter zero's.

Can't get to the bottom of it.

Any help appreciated.

[How Tutors Looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzRA1.png)
[How mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o84dx.png)

```
//My Mark Up//




<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="startStopBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="play"></i>
        </button>

        <button id="resetBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-left" id="reset"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

//Their Mark Up://

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="timer">
            00:00:00
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="startStopBtn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="play"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="resetBtn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-left" id="reset"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

//MY CSS://

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://d1s9j44aio5gjs.cloudfront.net/2021/10/Underwater-  empty-pool.jpg)
    no-repeat center top / cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
}

#timer {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 35px;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: none;
}

button i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
}

#play {
  background-color: green;
}
#pause {
  background-color: orange;
}
#reset {
  background-color: red;
}
```

//Their CSS//

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(img/project-4.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   }
   .container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  0 0 3px;
   }
   #timer {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 35px;
   }
   .buttons {
    text-align: center;
   }
   button {
    margin: 0 10px;
    border: none;
   }
   button i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
   }
   #play {
    background-color: green;
   }
   #pause {
    background-color: orange;
   }
   #reset {
    background-color: red;
   }
```

Comment: You target the class `.button` instead of `button`.

Comment: If you give the timer element a background color you will see it is wider than the container, but the text is centered ok within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have given timer a width of 100% AND side padding of 35px.

Assuming you haven't changed the default setting for box-sizing it will have the value of content-box by default - so the overall width will be 100% (the width of the parent, .container), plus 2x35px.

You can see this if you put a background color on the timer element.

You could just remove the side padding as the text-align: center will ensure you get as much padding (ie blank space either side of the text) as possible.

However, your tutor's code has the padding in it so I suspect they have a blanket setting for box-sizing. You often see this in stylesheets:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[such settings also often include margin: 0; to get rid of the default margins set by browsers].

Worth asking.

Here's 'your code' with the box-sizing set and, incidentally, the dot removed from in front of the button settings in the stylesheet.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      background: url(https://d1s9j44aio5gjs.cloudfront.net/2021/10/Underwater-empty-pool.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 60%;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 30px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    #timer {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 72px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 35px;
      background: cyan;
    }
    
    .buttons {
      text-align: center;
      background: pink;
    }
    
    button {
      margin: 0 10px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    button i {
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    #play {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    #pause {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    
    #reset {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="startStopBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="play"></i>
        </button>

        <button id="resetBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-left" id="reset"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Note: with that large font-size there could be occasions when the time still flows outside the container - try squishing the width of the viewport right down. You may like to think about this if you are supporting very narrow devices and introduce some responsive sizing - for example making the font-size dependant on the vw unit.

Note also that the image in the background wasn't showing because of spurious spaces in the url so I've removed them.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the `width` from `#timer` or give it a `max-width: 100%;` instead of `width: 100%;`.

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://d1s9j44aio5gjs.cloudfront.net/2021/10/Underwater-empty-pool.jpg)
    no-repeat center top / cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
}

#timer {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 35px;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="startStopBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="play"></i>
        </button>

        <button id="resetBtn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-left" id="reset"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there might be some different between your browser's default stylesheet vs the tutor's.

The way I would fix this is to change `box-sizing` of `#timer` to be `border-box`. You can find more detail about that attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). You can see that with `content-box`, it behaves like your example as it doesn't take padding as part of element width so it overflows when you set the element width to 100%.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px;
}

#timer {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 35px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This is what you need if you use padding otherwise the padding won't get considered */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `width:100%` from `#timer`
or replace it with `max-width:100%`

100% width does not leave any space for margin.

margin:0 auto will work only on a width less than 100%.